# Ionic App - After Splash Screen Goes Away, Won't Display Loaded Data Until Reopening of App

Tags: ios, ionic-framework

I have no idea what would cause this issue, or even how to begin debugging it.

I've checked all of the plugins to be sure they're installed, and they are. This does this on both the Emulator and the Physical Device. No errors in the XCode console are thrown. Running the app in the browser, I don't have this issue, and also it doesn't shed any light on the issue.

Currently I'm working with an Ionic v1 app where the app shows data from an API call on load. Except, it won't show up in iOS until I send the app to the background and then bring it back.

Here are two screenshots:

1) Initial App Opening:

[image: Initial App Opening]

2) After Sending the App to Background, and Reopening Again:

[image: After reopening the app]

Any thoughts, ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a very difficult bug to figure out.

This is the solution thread:

https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/6928

The *key* was that this meta tag in the html had to have this part in it:

`default-src 'self' gap://ready file://* *;`

Also, if you're wondering how I even saw the issue, as it didn't show up in the browser tests:

I had to load it into either the Simulator or my Physical Device, open up Safari Browser in OSX and go to the Develop tab. Find the proper device and then I can see the app to open the developer tools for. The console then allowed me to see any issues in the app as well as do any necessary step debugging.

In this case, it was throwing this error:

Refused to load gap://ready because it appears in neither the child-src directive nor the default-src directive of the Content Security Policy.

Answer (score 0):

=> Check if you are setting proper variable's value which is used in html.